# Strategies for solving rational Diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

Are there any strategies for solving Diophantine equations where the solutions can be any rational number, not just an integer, besides substituting $x=p/q$ and $y=r/s$, with $p,q,r,s$ integers with $\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(r,s)=1$?

How can one, in general, use the condition $\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(r,s)=1$ well?

I'm mainly interested in the type that appear on contests, so please don't suggest to use modular or elliptic curves to solve it, unless it is a special form that doesn't need the massive calculations it usually needs.

Comment: The strategy is, but it is unlikely You need.  You are asking something that You probably do not like it.  Rational parameterization usually boils down to this. $x=\frac{p}{q}$ ; $y=\frac{r}{q}$ ; $z=\frac{s}{q}$ .....

Comment: What techniques do you know when solving for integer Diophantine equations? Most of the time (there are not that many rational diophantine equations in olympiads) you can solve them with those techniques.

Comment: Then it won't be a Diophantine Equation.